# AJAX form duplicates fields

Tags: forms, ajax

I am following the ajax_example.module in the example module closely.  Essentially, I have  a fieldset with several fields inside.  The user fills out these fields, clicks 'add more', and then another fieldset loads beneath it via AJAX.
[image: a form with an AJAX-enabled button to load an additional fieldset]

My form works fine for up to three entries.  But, after a third entry is added, it begins duplicating fieldsets.

[image]

The logic that generates the form is a simple for loop; it should work the same for 1 or 100 values, and I'm not really sure why the duplicates are being generated.  What's even more perplexing is that if I examine $form in a debugger, the form elements are all where they should be, and there are no duplicates.

Code overview: I have a page that calls this form.  The form has a button with the 'ajax' property, and when clicked, it adds 1 to $form_state['item_quantity'].  Then, it regenerates the form, and a for loop creates one fieldset per item_quantity.  There is a conditional to check if this is the last item, which will add a special CSS class if true.

```
function manual_import_form($form, &$form_state) {
  //set up options for select list
  $task_options = get_task_options();
  $location_options = get_location_options();
  $model_options = get_model_options();

  $form['#attached'] = array(
    'css' => array(
      'type' => 'file',
      'data' => drupal_get_path('module','manual_import') . '/manual_import.css',
    ),
  );
  $form['#tree'] = TRUE;
  $form['scenario'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Import Scenario'),
    '#options' => array(
      'shipment' => t('Shipment'),
      'location' => t('Location'),
      'manual' => t('Manual'),

      ),
    '#default_value' => 'shipment',
  );
  $form['scenario_shipment'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Associate Group To Shipment'),
    '#description' => t('Associate a group of items to a shipment, and auto-generate tasks'),
    '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="scenario"]' => array('value' => 'shipment'),
      ),
    ),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collasped' => FALSE,
  );
  $form['scenario_shipment']['shipping_list_number'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Shipping List Number'),
    '#prefix' => '<div class="manual-import-shipping-list">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );
  $form['scenario_shipment']['shipping_from'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Shipping From'),
    '#options' => $location_options,
    '#default_value' => 283,
  );
  $form['scenario_shipment']['shipping_to'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Shipping To'),
    '#options' => $location_options,
    '#default_value' => 283,
  );

  $form['scenario_location'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Associate Group To Location'),
    '#description' => t('Associate a group of items to a location, and auto-generate tasks'),
    '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="scenario"]' => array('value' => 'location'),
      ),
    ),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collasped' => FALSE,
  );
  $form['scenario_location']['location'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Location'),
    '#options' => $location_options,
    '#default_value' => 283,
  );
  $form['scenario_manual'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Manually Create Tasks'),
    '#description' => t('Manually select the tasks to be created for the items in the group.'),
    '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="scenario"]' => array('value' => 'manual'),
      ),
    ),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collasped' => FALSE,
  );
  $form['scenario_manual']['task'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Task Type'),
    '#options' => $task_options,
  );
  $form['import_items'] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="import_items">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );
  if (empty($form_state['import_item_quantity'])) {
      $form_state['import_item_quantity'] = 1;
  }
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $form_state['import_item_quantity']; $i++) {
    $form['import_items'][$i] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('Import Item @item', array('@item' => $i)),
      '#collapsible' => TRUE,
      '#collapsed' => FALSE,
    );
    $form['import_items'][$i]['ticket_number'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#maxlength' => 32,
      '#title' => t('Ticket Number'),
      '#class' => 'manual-import-item-field',
      '#prefix' => '<div class="manual-import-item-field manual-import-item-ticket">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
    $form['import_items'][$i]['device_id'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#maxlength' => 32,
      '#title' => t('Device ID'),
      '#prefix' => '<div class="manual-import-item-field manual-import-item-device-id">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
    $form['import_items'][$i]['device_model'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Make/Model'),
      '#options' => $model_options,
      '#prefix' => '<div class="manual-import-item-field manual-import-item-device>',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
    if ($i == $form_state['import_item_quantity']) {
      $form['import_items'][$i]['device_model']['#prefix'] = 
        '<div class="manual-import-item-field manual-import-item-device manual-import-item-last">';
    }
  }
  $form['import_items']['item_add'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Add another!',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'manual_import_item_ajax_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'import_items',
    ),
    '#submit' => array('manual_import_item_add'),
  );
  xdebug_break();
  return $form;
}


function manual_import_item_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['import_items'];
}


function manual_import_item_add($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['import_item_quantity']++;
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in your CSS.

```
$form['import_items'][$i]['device_model']
```

Is missing a double quote on the #prefix.
Change To:

```
 '#prefix' => '<div class="manual-import-item-field manual-import-item-device">',
```

Comment: You're right; the missing quotation marks were interfering with the div structure, which compounded after every iteration.  With the quotes in place, it's working normally now; thank you.